Pandas plot - unable to set xticks
I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart using pandas dataframe plot method. The x values are floats and I am trying to set xticks at integer intervals with no success. Here is my code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [[0.0, 4.9, 19.9, 8.1, 0.0], [0.12, 4.5, 27.0, 10.1, 0.0], 
        [0.24, 2.8, 9.3, 4.6, 0.0], [0.36, 2.2, 9.1, 2.7, 0.0], 
        [0.48, 2.2, 7.3, 3.1, 0.0], [1.0, 4.9, 26.4, 11.2, 0.0], 
        [1.12, 5.9, 25.3, 8.7, 0.0], [1.24, 3.7, 13.3, 7.1, 0.0], 
        [1.3599999999999999, 3.0, 9.5, 3.4, 0.0], [1.48, 3.2, 8.9, 4.7, 0.0], 
        [2.0, 8.4, 24.8, 20.2, 0.0], [2.12, 9.5, 19.3, 22.5, 0.0], 
        [2.24, 5.7, 11.8, 6.6, 0.0], [2.36, 4.1, 11.1, 5.1, 0.0], 
        [2.48, 5.4, 8.0, 4.6, 0.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['xval', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], data = data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x = 'xval', kind = 'bar', ax = ax, stacked = True)
xticks = [x for x in df['xval'] if int(x) == x]
ticklabel = ['{:.1f}'.format(x) for x in xticks]
ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels = ticklabel)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig('mychart.png')



well, your list comprehension only returns 3 values [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]. what are you expecting it to return?

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [
    [0.0, 4.9, 19.9, 8.1, 0.0],
    [0.12, 4.5, 27.0, 10.1, 0.0],
    [0.24, 2.8, 9.3, 4.6, 0.0],
    [0.36, 2.2, 9.1, 2.7, 0.0],
    [0.48, 2.2, 7.3, 3.1, 0.0],
    [1.0, 4.9, 26.4, 11.2, 0.0],
    [1.12, 5.9, 25.3, 8.7, 0.0],
    [1.24, 3.7, 13.3, 7.1, 0.0],
    [1.3599999999999999, 3.0, 9.5, 3.4, 0.0],
    [1.48, 3.2, 8.9, 4.7, 0.0],
    [2.0, 8.4, 24.8, 20.2, 0.0],
    [2.12, 9.5, 19.3, 22.5, 0.0],
    [2.24, 5.7, 11.8, 6.6, 0.0],
    [2.36, 4.1, 11.1, 5.1, 0.0],
    [2.48, 5.4, 8.0, 4.6, 0.0],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["xval", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"], data=data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x="xval", kind="bar", ax=ax, stacked=True)
xticks, ticklabels = zip(*[(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(df["xval"]) if x.is_integer()])
ax.set_xticks(xticks, ticklabels)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("mychart.png")


It seems to me that the issue with the original approach is that the x-axis isn't actually using some real number line (since the bars wouldn't be equally spaced if something like that was happening). You can see this in action by reordering the rows of the data and seeing that the bars and labels will move around, regardless of whether things are sorted (easiest to see without the xticks-rewriting code).
Thus, the xticks should actually be the ordinal numbers of the relevant bars. In this case, the "0.0", "1.0", and "2.0" labels should be at bars 0, 5, and 10, respectively (not 0, 1, and 2).

My original issue is resolved. I have run into another issue. If I try adding annotations they are getting placed incorrectly. For e.g., I want to include a text labels (say Bar1, Bar2 ..) at the top of the bar.

@Nitin for i, patch in enumerate(ax.patches[-len(df) :]):     height = sum([patch.get_height() for patch in ax.patches[i :: len(df)]])     ax.annotate(         f"Bar{i+1}",         (patch.get_x() + patch.get_width() / 2, height),         ha="center",         size=8,     )

Thanks. Just curious. If I use ax.bar method (a little drawn out compared to df.plot) I don't run into this problem. Why so?

Not sure. This is probably a result of something specific about how the df.plot bar plot is implemented.

When you plot the bar graph the pandas plotting routine will actually put the bar ticks positions at integers (0-14 in your case), while labelling them with the actual x-values. What you can instead do is something like:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [[0.0, 4.9, 19.9, 8.1, 0.0], [0.12, 4.5, 27.0, 10.1, 0.0], 
        [0.24, 2.8, 9.3, 4.6, 0.0], [0.36, 2.2, 9.1, 2.7, 0.0], 
        [0.48, 2.2, 7.3, 3.1, 0.0], [1.0, 4.9, 26.4, 11.2, 0.0], 
        [1.12, 5.9, 25.3, 8.7, 0.0], [1.24, 3.7, 13.3, 7.1, 0.0], 
        [1.3599999999999999, 3.0, 9.5, 3.4, 0.0], [1.48, 3.2, 8.9, 4.7, 0.0], 
        [2.0, 8.4, 24.8, 20.2, 0.0], [2.12, 9.5, 19.3, 22.5, 0.0], 
        [2.24, 5.7, 11.8, 6.6, 0.0], [2.36, 4.1, 11.1, 5.1, 0.0], 
        [2.48, 5.4, 8.0, 4.6, 0.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['xval', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], data=data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x = 'xval', kind = 'bar', ax = ax, stacked = True)

labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
xticks = list(zip(ax.get_xticks(), df["xval"]))

# set the xtick positions for the equivalent integer bar positions
xtp = []
xtl = []
for (p, v) in xticks:
    # check for integer tick values
    if np.isclose(float(v) % 1.0, 0.0):
        # store required tick positions
        xtp.append(p)

        # store required tick labels
        xtl.append(f"{v:.1f}")

ax.set_xticks(xtp, labels=xtl)
ax.grid()



You might want to read about lurking precision issues: How to check if a float value is a whole number and maybe consider math.isclose().

Thanks, I've updated to have a better check for integers

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [[0.0, 4.9, 19.9, 8.1, 0.0], [0.12, 4.5, 27.0, 10.1, 0.0],
        [0.24, 2.8, 9.3, 4.6, 0.0], [0.36, 2.2, 9.1, 2.7, 0.0],
        [0.48, 2.2, 7.3, 3.1, 0.0], [1.0, 4.9, 26.4, 11.2, 0.0],
        [1.12, 5.9, 25.3, 8.7, 0.0], [1.24, 3.7, 13.3, 7.1, 0.0],
        [1.3599999999999999, 3.0, 9.5, 3.4, 0.0], [1.48, 3.2, 8.9, 4.7, 0.0],
        [2.0, 8.4, 24.8, 20.2, 0.0], [2.12, 9.5, 19.3, 22.5, 0.0],
        [2.24, 5.7, 11.8, 6.6, 0.0], [2.36, 4.1, 11.1, 5.1, 0.0],
        [2.48, 5.4, 8.0, 4.6, 0.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['xval', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], data = data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x = 'xval', kind = 'bar', ax = ax, stacked = True)
xticks = [x for x in df['xval'] ]
ticklabel = [x for x in xticks]
ax.grid()
fig.savefig('mychart.png')

produces:

